# how to delete all urls in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, url

I previously used an old CMS.

I moved to wordpress and I've done a lot of work, but I still have in my very old articles 1000+ internal links pointing to old urls.
I've set up redirects, but I would like to actually replace / delete the very old internal linking in the wordpress database.

I have 3 types of old linking :
/articles.php?lng=fr&pg=425  .......... so like /articles.php?stuff 
/news.php?lng=fr&pg=1827  .......... so like /news.php?stuff 
/2456-actualite  .......... so like /id-actualite

I believe that "Search and replace" and "Better search and replace", both Wordpress plugins are only dealing with exact urls, while the ids are dynamic.

How would you delete those all links in the database, but keeping the hypertext of those links?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably impossible to change each URL by hand.. much better way is to use something like this "https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/" to replace all URLs you need in the database. - This does not only deal with urls but with any other text too.

Comment: I've used that plugin before, but I do not seem to be able to use wildcards in it, and I do not know if using it to replace :  /articles.php    will replace all of /articles.php?xxxxxxx or not

Comment: and if I should just leave it empty for the replacement url, or # or... else?

Comment: It's should do the job to be fair. I would back up the database before doing anything and then try both methods you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ***[WP Cli](https://wp-cli.org/)***?

It's a very powerful tool for this kind of problems by running some commands on your server.

Example:

```
# Search and replace but skip one column
$ wp search-replace 'http://example.dev' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid
```

Have a look more on their ***[search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/)*** command.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, i'll see with a dev friend if it's possible to look into it as I dont know much about servers